# Unusually High Variance in a Nested Model

Tags: r, biostatistics, nested-data, variance-inflation-factor, nested-models

I have a dataset containing lizard home range estimates and several environmental variables. My end goal is to create a model that uses the best combination of environmental variables to predict home range size. Recently I have come across an issue in my analysis that I am confused on. I am trying to build a model in the coding program R to predict home range size based on my environmental variables.

Since all of my lizards come from one of eight populations, I am specifying that individual lizard (ID) is nested within each site (Site) using the following coding syntax: `(1|Site/ID)`. The problem is that when I assess colinearity of the model predictor variables using the `check_collinearity()` function from the performance package, I find that the variance inflation factor (VIF) is significantly higher than when I exclude Site as a predictor variable in the model. Furthermore, Site always has the highest VIF score out of all variables, and it is usually an extremely high value.

My question is, why does the Site variable have such a high VIF score, and why does its inclusion in the model result in higher VIF scores for all other variables? Does it have something to do with the fact that environmental conditions associated with lizards at the same site are bound to be very similar? If I am interested in looking at differences in home ranges betwen sites as well as individuals, is a nested model still appropriate for my goals, or is there a more appropriate way of building my model?